# page not found on jsp submission

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml, url-mapping

here is my test.jsp placed at webcontent/jsp/

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="employee.do" method="get">
<input type="text" name="name1">
<input type="submit" name="add employee" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now here is servlet mapping in `web.xml`

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>EmployeeServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.controller.EmployeeServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>EmployeeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/employee.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
```

Now when I submit this form to my employee.do then server says `page not found`.I dont know why it is happening?I am using tomcat server
**Edit:** When I place this jsp page outside the jsp folder , mean direct in the webcontent folder then it works fine and submit the form.Why it is not submitting the form under `jsp` folder

Comment: Check the request url in some http watch utility plugged in to your browser .

Comment: sorry i dont know about this http watch as i am new to java as well as web programming

Comment: Is the url /context/jsp/employee.do or /context/employee.do

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/CMS/jsp/employee.do?name1=fgnhbj&add+employee=Submit+Query` when I submit the form it goes to this url and shows page not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the jsp file directly under web-content or change the url mapping to /jsp/employee.do .

Comment: perfect :) thanks for your help.let me accept your answer after 4 mins according to my previliges :(